# Scalable RDBMS alternative, NoSQL, NewSQL

Tags: sql, mongodb, tidb

I am looking for scalable alternative to traditional DBMS like PostgreSQL or MySQL.
In traditional databases I don't have the following features:

- Auto sharding to ensure linear scalability.
- Replication with automatic failover and recovery to ensure high availability.
- No single point of failure.

MongoDB looks like good candidate if I can sacrifice transactions.

Also I've looked at several newSQL databases. NewSQL seems suitable for my purposes: VoltDB, TiDB, cockroachDB. But I'm worried about whethever they are production-ready.

May be there are extensions allowing to run postgreSQL or MySQL in clustered mode out of box.

Comment: Software recommendations are specifically outside the scope of Stack Overflow.  But given that Stack Exchange itself is built on relational database technology, perhaps your requirements are a bit extreme.

Comment: I know that it's possible to scale relational databases and many big companies do that. But it's really difficult and I hope that there are databases that support this out of box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TiDB](https://pingcap.com/index)

- Compatibility with MySQL

It supports the MySQL Protocol so that you can transfer your MySQL scripts running on TiDB without change.

- Use cases

It was used by many big name company such as [Mobike](https://mobike.com/us/), uber，pinterest etc. In Mobike, the big data team uses TiDB as a slave for synchronizing data with online DB. After that, OLTP query, consisting of analysis and gathering request, was executed in such circumstance. Last but not the least, the cloud computing platform belongs to [Tencent](https://cloud.tencent.com/document/product/626/11567), the technology giant, recommend customers use HTAP based on TiDB for OLTP and OLAP.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Vitess](http://vitess.io). It's used at YouTube and by a few other companies.

PS: I work on that project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Traditional DBMS with suitable utils seems to be a good choice.